# IWebBrowser2 interfaces dependency graph

Tags: c++, c, com, iwebbrowser2

Is there interfaces dependency graph for IWebBrowser2 component?
I just want to make it clear what kind of dependencies exist between interfaces and who calls who?

Comment: Never seen one.  Standard problem, you run out of paper before running out of interfaces on these kind of complicated object models.

Comment: At times I found images like in this article quite helpful (showing some of the dependencies): http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/system/security/article.php/c5697 But in general: +1 @Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dependencywalker http://www.dependencywalker.com/  on the file shdocvw.dll